# How to split WCF service's Operation contracts into Concurrency mode as Single and Multiple

Tags: wcf, concurrency, singleton

I have one service Service A with 2 operation contract CheckServer and AddService. As the Service is singleton with Concurrey mode as Single
[ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single)]

```
public Class Service : Iservice
{
   public bool CheckService()
    {
       //Checks server avilabality and returns bool value
    }

   public int AddService(int a, int b)
    {
      return int i = a + b;
    }
}
```

Here my requirement is only one Instace of AddService to be allowed, so I made this as singleton. Now CheckServvice is not necessary to be Singleton so how can I split these 2 method implementation to make AddService as singleton and CheckService as multiple.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WCF doesn't provide what you want. Put that logic outside of WCF and write your own synchronization logic. For example implement singleton class exposing `CheckService` and `AddService` where synchronization will be directly in `AddService` method and `CheckService` method will be free to call.

Make standard WCF per-call service delegating processing to your singleton class.